# Why the need to say "je l'ai été" instead of "je l'étais"?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

> Vous avez l'air d'être l'un d'eux, comme je **l'ai été** moi-même, autrefois.
>
> Vous avez l'air d'être l'un d'eux, comme je **l'étais** moi-même, autrefois.

The phrase "I used to be one of them myself" indicates that this particular state continued for an unknown period of time, rather than being a one-time event.

So I assumed that the use of Imparfait "je l'étais" might make more sense here, but it looks like "je l'ai été" is the correct form to use. I wonder why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, the choice of the tense expresses a different aspect of the action.

- > Vous avez l'air d'être l'un d'eux, comme je l'ai été moi-même, autrefois.

  *Passé composé*: focuses on the action/state itself with no reference to the duration. It can mean it did not last long, but not necessarily.<sup>1</sup>
- > Vous avez l'air d'être l'un d'eux, comme je l'étais moi-même, autrefois.

  *Imparfait*: focuses on the duration of the action/state and implies it lasted for quite some time. The subject of the predicate, "*je*", is given more importance.<sup>2</sup>

  ---

If a translation into English is any help:
<sup>1</sup> ..., as I once was.
<sup>2</sup> ... as I used to be.

Comment: Regarding "The subject of the predicate is given more importance.", does this mean that the second version places emphasis on the word "je"? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA, yes, it does in this sentence.  I think it much depends on the context and the difference between *passé composé* and *imparfait* is often subtle. Here we must also consider that the *passé composé* refers to a past action and not to the present.