# Why is it 'Il a été rédacteur' and not 'Il était rédacteur'?

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait

> *J'aurais aimé être acteur ou écrivain...Je gagne donc ma vie en étant simple petit employé de banque. Après tout, Paul Valéry, le grand poète philosophe, **n'a-t-il pas été** simplement rédacteur dans un ministère?*

One's job can be treated as a long-time habit, thus, shouldn't verb être be conjugated in the imparfait instead of the passé composé? I've searched the internet and I've found both versions available. Examples:

> • Il **était** médecin dans l'armée coréenne.
>
> • Avant de prendre sa retraite, il **a été** médecin de famille pendant plusieurs....

Comment: Related/duplicate https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33368/il-a-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-constat%c3%a9-ou-il-%c3%a9tait-constat%c3%a9?rq=1 https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/why-the-need-to-say-je-lai-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-instead-of-je-l%c3%a9tais?rq=1

Comment: The imparfait would mean that rédacteur dans un ministère was Paul Valéry's main or even only job during his lifetime while the passé composé suggests that was only for a limited period of time.